# I am not getting any output & error and i don't know why

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am not getting any output and i don't know why but im not getting an error neither in the browser nor in the command prompt so im not clear about what is happening. And I got an error in the starting of the execution like this error:

> WebSocketClient.js:16 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/ws' failed

then the error fade away and didn't appear after reloading and I get only one error in the google something like error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

this error in got while executing in the browser. So i don't know what's the error itself

this is my server side code

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import cors from "cors";
import postRoutes from "./routes/posts.js";

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
app.use(cors());
app.use("/posts",postRoutes);


// mongodb connection
const CONNECTION_URL = "mongodb+srv://memory:memory1213@abscluster.f5vt7.mongodb.net/? 
retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

mongoose.connect(CONNECTION_URL, { useNewUrlParser:true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
.then(() => app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("server running on port :",PORT)
}))
.catch((error) => console.log(error.message))

/* mongoose.set("useFindAndModify", false); */
```

client side (app.js)

```
import React,{useEffect} from "react";
import { Container, AppBar, Typography, Grow, Grid} from "@material-ui/core";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import {getPosts} from "./actions/posts";
import memories from "./images/memories-Logo.png"
import Posts from "./components/Posts/Posts";
import Form from "./components/Form/Form";
import useStyles from "./styles";

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(()=> {
    dispatch(getPosts());
  },[getPosts])
  return (
    <Container maxWidth="lg">
      <AppBar className={classes.appBar} position="static" color="inherit">
        <Typography className={classes.heading} variant="h2" align="center">Memories</Typography>
        <img className={classes.image} src={memories} alt="memories" height="60"/>
      </AppBar>
      <Grow in>
        <Container>
          <Grid container justifyContent="space-between" alignItems="stretch" spacing={3}>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={7}>
                <Posts />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
                <Form />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Container>
      </Grow>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default App;
```

client side (index.js)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { legacy_createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from "./reducers"

const store = legacy_createStore(reducers, compose(applyMiddleware(thunk)))

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

[image]

Comment: can you please share the code in git so I can install and check what is the issue? I also want to see what is the code posts.js

Comment: I will share the link: https://github.com/Abraar07/Nodejs-AOSC and thanks for trying to help me out .

Comment: I will check and get back to you for sure

Comment: I'm not able to connect database because my IP is not whitelisted and if I directly run then it is showing this message on submitting the form {
    "message": "Operation `postmessages.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms"
}

Comment: I commented the mongoose connection code and added this at the end of the file app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`));

Comment: can u get the output ?

Comment: Now try the database connection bcz I have changed the network to "Allow access from anywhere "

Comment: app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(Listening on port ${PORT}));  
I have tried this code but it shows error to me.

Comment: I will check tomorrow morning as it is nighttime

Comment: It is fixed and I'm adding answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

change this const posts = useStyles(); to const posts = useSelector((state) => state.posts);

I think you have made a typo here but if you use above then it will show [image]

Comment: It is Posts.js and you can also search the above code

Comment: Thanks for helping me out . How did u understand the error and try to find it out .
can u explain to me?

Comment: You are using Redux and using useSelector you can call the state which you have set in the store. The problem was you have called const posts= useStyles() and you are passing this to render the post which is irrelevant

Comment: can you mark answer as complete if above one helps you ?

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: There must a checkbox ✅ where my answer is. You can click to make it completed

Comment: You can’t do because you need at least 15 reputation

Comment: I have got another error can u help me with that as I cannot post a question now.

Comment: Okay comment here

Comment: devforhelp008@gmail.com

Comment: I have fixed but not able to push to repo

Comment: Thanks for your help not a problem about repo . I  have also fixed the error and I think it was something version error.